# How to tell when Ruby's OpenURI open() function gives a 404 page not found error?

Tags: ruby, exception, open-uri

I want to grab the contents of a webpage like this:

```
open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/")
```

However, sometimes, that page doesn't exist:

```
open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/blabla.html")
```

The `open` command throws an exception. I know I can catch that exception, but it seems inappropriate in my case. I know there will regularly be bad URLs because visitors and users type in URLs to retrieve.

I don't like the idea of using exceptions for this regular situation. Is there a way that I can know the page was not found without an exception being thrown?

Comment: The only regular outcome of `open` is the resource being opened. Everything else is exceptional, and should be handled via exceptions.

Comment: Not in any particular order, but [HTTPClient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient), [RESTClient](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client), [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus), [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) or [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) all would be easier than Net::HTTP. Mechanize can retrieve a page, but that's not its reason for existence. Any of the previous gems would be a better fit for regular HTTP I/O. OpenURI is a great tool and I use it often but it's not the most flexible thing out there, so exceptions are your only choice.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a simplified method to read a file (`open-uri`), so you're getting a simplified result for errors.  It's just not a robust way of doing things beyond simple success/fail.

Check out using [`Net::HTTP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)  (specifically the `request` method) or [`Mechanize`](http://rubygems.org/gems/mechanize) or many other available APIs for such tasks.